# how to write rspec for private method in controller with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rspec, private

I have controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end

  private

    def handle_login_sequence
      username = params[:userName]
      password = params[:password]

      cookies[:locale]  = params[:locale]
      remember          = params[:remember]

      username_locked   = User.locked_username?(username)
      user = User.authenticate(username, password)

      if user && user.has_portal_access?
        case user.account_status
          when AccountStatus::Active
            flash[:error] =  'login'
        end
      end
    end

end
```

I want to write Rspec for this private method

```
@controller = ApplicationController.new
@controller.send(:handle_login_sequence)
```

By the above code I can call `handle_login_sequence` method but I don't know how to pass the below:

```
params[:userName], params[:password], params[:locale], params[:remember]
```

Comment: What does your spec look like so far?

Comment: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base. The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

(I gave put inside teh method that was printed)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't test private methods of a controller directly. Instead, test the controller action that uses this method.

Don't forget about black box metaphor with regards to your controllers.

[image: Black Box testing diagram]

If you test private methods, you'll have to rewrite tests when you want to change the just the implementation and not the interface. Black box tests will help you to make sure that you haven't broken your controller functionality without directly testing the private methods.

Comment: From your post i understood as don't worry about the input access the method only. Is it right. If i call the method without sending params that showing the following error
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base. The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]